# Как сделать одноэкранный сайт на bootstrap?

Tags: css3, html5, bootstrap

Как сделать одноэкранный сайт на bootstrap 4, чтобы контент не мог вылезти?

`overflow: hidden` - не подходит из-за обрезания контекта при масштабировании.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете 4ый бутсрап, то там появились [классы](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/), которые задают размер содержимого в зависимости от ширины и высоты. Так, например можете задать вашему контейнеру классы `.h-100`, `.w-100`. Или можете сами прописать стили в единицах wh, wv.

*P.S. Очень расплывчатый вопрос. Конкретный ответ на него дать невозможно. В такой постановке задачи многое зависит от макета, от тз. Каждая задача уникальна, и почему не получается именно у вас можно только гадать, без кода, без макета, без тз... ну просто невозможно.*